# Send master details form in one shot

Tags: extjs, extjs4

My app have a form, where the user insert  a master record (medical prescription) and insert some detais (drugs).

I need to send this all in one call to server (now I working with rails).

How can I do this using extjs 4?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this problem, buildind a string with content of all child records. In the server I made a "eval" in this string to save as an array.

Ex.:

```
[{drug_id:1, morning: "1", night: "2"}, {drug_id:2, morning: "0", night: "1"},...]
```

Comment: Eval is a evil. Don't do it for your security.